# I can't seem to get my background video to play in the background

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to get my video to play in the background of my website but for some reason, it gets on top of all of the other content on the site. I don't know whats going on.

CSS

```css
.fullscreen {
    position:static;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: -100;
             }

.fullscreen-vd {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media (max-width: 0px) {
    .fullscreen {
        background: url('gif.mp4') center center / cover no-repeat;
    }
    .fullscreen-vd {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="fullscreen">
            <video loop autoplay muted poster="IMG_25062017_221924_0.png" class="fullscreen-vd">
    <source src="gif.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this update some css part and remove some part to get it, And you haven't any `width` and `height` to video, so i used `100%` `height` and `width` for video.

If you used a fixed `height` and `width` for video then use `fullscreen-vd` class to align `center` `vertically` and `horizontally` to your video.

*I posted a working snippet, Hope it will help you.*

**[As your requirement fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lokeshg27/1v5fdpL5/)**

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%; /* For take full height and width */
  height: 100%;
}

.fullscreen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -100;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* NO NEED BECAUSE YOUR VIDEO IS OCCUPY FULL HEIGHT AND WIDTH */

/* .fullscreen-vd {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
} */

.content {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 0px) {
  .fullscreen {
    background: url('gif.mp4') center center / cover no-repeat;
  }
  .fullscreen-vd {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen">
  <video width="100%" loop autoplay muted poster="IMG_25062017_221924_0.png" >
<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/mp4">
<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/webm">
</video>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>
    HELLO
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need it center assign a width and height and use `fullscreen-vd ` to get center